# How to get Tab key click event on wrtting on text field?

Tags: javascript

can you please tell me how to get Tab key  event in jquery ? Actually If user click Tab key while entering text in input field I want to show alert .

I am using this But not working ..

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("caseName");
    if(myInput.addEventListener ) {
        myInput.addEventListener('keydown',this.keyHandler,false);
    } else if(myInput.attachEvent ) {
        myInput.attachEvent('onkeydown',this.keyHandler); /* damn IE hack */
    }

    function keyHandler(e) {
        alert("Hi")
        var TABKEY = 9;
        if(e.keyCode == TABKEY) {
            this.value += "    ";
            alert("Tab")
            if(e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what about it is not working?

Comment: And why do you tag this question jQuery? I don't see any. But if you use it, it makes it so much easier.

Comment: ye s but I am not geting alert

Comment: my thoughts exactly @putvande

Comment: I will explain more I have one text field .when I enter text LIke "a,b c" I am getting alert Hi .But when I click TAB button it not give alert TAB

Comment: It Is jquery problem I am using jquery in my project +android

Comment: It is same problem Like if user click enter button ( shift button).and get the event

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the this keyword in the following lines:

```
myInput.addEventListener('keydown',this.keyHandler,false);
```

and change it to :

```
myInput.addEventListener('keydown',keyHandler,false);
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aMcJ3/) fiddle out.